# comment field always detected empty in laravel

Tags: php, forms, laravel-5, comments, posts

I'm working on laravel 5.2. My comment box's textarea is always detected empty. I've specified my post_id along with.Every other formalities have also been done.

**Controller:**

```
public function postReply(Request $request, $post_id) {

    $data = $request::all();
    // Applying validation rules.
    $rules = array("reply-{ $post_id }" => 'required|max:1000');
    $val = Validator::make($data, $rules);
    if ($val->passes()) {
        dd('all ok');
    } else {
        $message = 'There is an error';
    }
    return redirect()->route('home')->with(['message' => $message]);
}
```

**Form:**

```
<form action="{{ route('post.reply',['post_id' => $post->id]) }}" 
      method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" name=" reply-{{ $post->id }} " rows="2" 
                  placeholder = "Reply to this Post"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"> Reply </button>
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ Session::token() }}" name="_token">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue here :

```
$data = $request::all();
```

should be

```
$data = $request->all();
```

Or like this :

```
public function postReply(Request $request)
        {
            // Here you are passing class so all is member of Request Class.
            $data=$request->all()
            // Applying validation rules.
            $rules = [
               'post_id' => 'required|max:1000'
            ];
            $val = Validator::make($data, $rules);
            if($val->passes())
            {
                dd('all ok');
            }
            else
            {
                $message= 'There is an error'; 
            }
            return redirect()->route('home')->with(['message' => $message]);
        }
```

Comment: Actually all other functions on same page are working with $request::all().Using this it gives an error, Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::all().Since i'm using use Request; instead of use Illuminate\Http\Request;and it works fine.Please suggest any other edit.